# Does Colossus have powers beyond his body becoming metal?

Tags: marvel, powers, colossus

We all know he is stronger and more durable when in his organic metal form. My question is does he have additional powers? Specifically energy based ones. I only ask this because the Marvel Wiki gives him [an "energy projection" rating of 5](https://marvel.com/universe/Colossus#axzz4kWqmH2kj).

The energy level of 5 seems to indicate [long ranged projectile energy](http://marvel.com/universe/OHOTMU:Power_Grids#axzz4kWqmH2kj) but I have never seen this nor can Google provide an example.

Comment: I think he also does energy projection? Can’t remember any examples of this though.

Comment: Maybe there's also some cross-contamination from the side-scrolling beat-em-up arcade game where his special ability let him emit an energy blast?

Comment: *"We all know he is stronger and more durable when in his organic metal form."* The [Colossus](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Piotr_Rasputin_(Earth-1610)) from Ultimate universe (Earth 1610) he didn't have any kind of super strength, so he couldn't even _move_ when he was in "metal form". He had to [take a drug](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Banshee_(Mutant_Growth_Hormone)) for that. He did it for years until he was found out and expelled.

Comment: Perhaps they’re referring to the Fastball Special?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[Colossus](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Piotr_Rasputin_(Earth-616)), with his standard power set, does not possess any energy projection abilities, and his only known power is his mutation that allows him to transform his body into an organic metal substance. Transforming into and maintaining his metal form does involve a form of bio-energy, but he cannot project this as a form of attack, it simply exists within him like a kind of life force.

However, different story arcs in comics over the years have given him other abilities. Note that these are all former powers and he no longer possesses them:

- **Juggernaut** - During the "Fear Itself" event, Colossus offered himself to be Cyttorak's new Avatar for the powers of Juggernaut. As a result, he gained all the power of an Unstoppable Force... made of Osmium.
- **Phoenix** - During "Avengers vs. X-Men", Colossus was briefly an Avatar of Phoenix, along with 4 other Mutants. He still had the powers of Juggernaut at this time. As an Avatar of the Phoenix Force, he gained immense levels of power, including the ability to use the cosmic flames of the Phoenix. I'm not sure if that counts as energy projection, but the ability to manipulate cosmic flames that can burn in the vacuum of space has to be pretty close.
- **War** - In "Omega World", Colossus was revealed to be a Horseman of War. While he doesn't seem to have gained any energy projection abilities as a result of Apocalypse's influence, he was able to shift his organic metal body much like the more advanced Terminators in Terminator 2 & 3. This allowed him to extend and effectively project his organic metal body, which we already know is a form of bio-energy. Again, I don't think it really counts, but he is technically projecting bio-energy as a power, so I thought I'd list it anyway.

Other than this, there doesn't seem to be any suggestion that he could project energy in the same way that most magic users can. This is probably why the Marvel Database more correctly lists his Energy Projection rating as 1.

Comment: Not sure how canon it is, but he can exert an energy field around him in the X-Men arcade game. It's not a long range energy projectile but it's the closest to an energy attack I could remember.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LzbjZEfTz1w - I dunno, he sort of.... explodes? And he seems to revert back to his regular human skin whilst doing so, like he's overcharging himself with bio-energy and letting it loose, temporarily causing him to not be made of metal until the bio-energy restabilises. I suppose I _did_ say that War letting him make organic metal tentacles counted as a kind of energy projection, so this would count too, but you're right that the game is in no way canonical, so..... I won't put it in the answer, but I'll give you a +1 :P

Answer (score 1):

Colossus possesses a few *subsidiary* abilities in relation to his "Ability to turn into organic metal". These are more consequences of the main power. They include:

1. Complete self-sustainability: In his armored form, he requires no food or oxygen; it's been theorized he doesn't even "need" sleep in that form.
2. Retarded aging: There was a period in the 90s where Piotyr was unable to change back into his human form. It was beast, I believe who theorized while in that state, he was literally free of naturally cellular degradation and copying, meaning he wasn't "aging" in any way.
3. Functional immunity from all bio-toxins. In that form, Colossus is essentially protected from most known normal forms of bio-hazards. He has to sanitize himself afterwards, usually in some form of intense heat, to kill any possible microbes before he changes back.
4. Enhanced reflexes. Piotyr's enhanced strength and explosivity naturally produces greater speed, stamina and power than normal. So while by no means a "speedster", Peter can react and move with greater speed than others, and is surprisingly agile, even in his armored form.

It *has* been theorized that Colossus actually **shifting** to his armored form *can* produce an excess in energy release, but several comics have shown him shifting while holding onto or being near others, and there have been no damage to them, so I'm not certain how accurate this is.